# How do I fix a hole in drywall?

Tags: repair, drywall

There is a hole in my drywall from a doorknob repeatedly hitting it, is there a straightforward way to fix it?

Comment: How big is the hole?  Different techniques can be employeed depending on the size.  A picture may help.

Comment: Is it a dent or a hole?

Comment: Jon's answer is great, but you want to consider stopping the hole reappearing. I'd suggest you affix a doorstop to either the floor, the wall or the door...

Comment: [This question might be helpful](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/128/33)

Comment: but... but... I didn't *mean* it, I didn't mean to hurt *anyone* :(

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Depending on the size of the hole, there are different methods to fix.

Small holes - As @Oscilatingcretin says just some spackle, sand, and paint you are done.

Medium holes - A fist size hole or bigger is harder.  Cleanup the hole area.  Then take one or more more pieces of strapping and attach to existing wall to serve as foundation for the replacement piece of drywall.  Cut replacement piece of drywall and fit to opening, attach to strapping installed previously.  Then just fill in the gaps and screws with mud, sand, and paint.

Here's a diagram to help to visualize, let's say the hole is the wall is around 6" by 6":
[image: Medium size holes fixup]

Larger holes - Most likely you will have to find the nearest stud to the left and right and make the existing hole bigger so that the new piece of drywall can be attached directly to the stud.   For the top and bottom, you will have to cut some strapping or framing so the the replacement piece can be secured to the top and bottom as well, otherwise the seem will crack.  Once the framing is in place, cut the replacement piece and secure to studs and new framing.  Tape, mud and sand around the edges of your new piece.  Paint.  If done well and the mud is feathered out, one will not notice the replacement piece of drywall.

Here's a diagram to help to visualize, lets say the hole is 12" by 12":
[image: Large size holes fixup]

For holes larger than that, probably best to replace the entire wall.

Comment: Strapping is a new term to me, but I believe it is the same thing as furring strips, 1x2 or 1x3 utility boards.

Comment: Correct.  Basically its a piece of wood that can fits in the cavity of the hole that the piece of drywall can screw to.  You could use anything from a scrap piece of 2x4 to a paint stirrer.  Usually as you have indicated 1x2 or 1x3 utility boards work best as they provide enough foundation and are easy to manuever in the hole.

Comment: What about a blowout patch?

Comment: Also to prevent the hole from happening again door stops (springs with rubber ends) can be attached at the based of the door or on the wall where the rubber will hit the skirting board or door. The cost around $2 to $5 from Home Depot.

Answer (score 5):

While it's not as attractive as fixing the wall, you can make the hole go away (if it's small) and prevent new ones with a wall protector like [this one from Canadian Tire](http://www.canadiantire.ca/AST/browse/3/HouseHome/Furniture/FurnitureProtection/PRD~0461830P/Door+Knob+Wall+Guard,+3-in.jsp?locale=en) (doubtless equivalents exist where you live.) It's just a white circle of plastic, 3" across. The back is sticky; you stick it to the wall and you're done. $2.99. I did this for an instant fix in two places and I'll get around to the actual repair thing later.

Answer (score 4):

spackle if it's a small hole.  a drywall repair kit if it's a big hole.  after you fix it, a wall-mounted door stopper will keep it from happening again

Answer (score 4):

In  addition to the other answers, you can also get a self-adhesive aluminum patch which you stick on.  It is thin enough that you just stick and then mud.  It's more expensive than any other method, but maybe less work, depending on the situation and your skill level.

http://reviews.homedepot.com/1999/100403177/8-in-x-8-in-drywall-repair-self-adhesive-wall-patch-reviews/reviews.htm

Comment: Just to add to this old answer - while it's definitely easier to use the adhesive patches, you have to build up the mud a bit in order to adequately cover up the mesh.  I find that it takes more finishing work to blend everything in and completely cover the mesh.