# How can I reattach this pivot bracket for bifold doors to the wall?

Tags: repair, doors, drywall, patching-drywall

I decided to repaint my bedroom a few weeks ago.  I removed the closet door in preparation for it, then painted the room.  I went to reattach the closet door and noticed that the pivot bracket on the ground wasn't screwed in to anything.  Looking closer, it seems that the drywall it was attached to has disintegrated.

Bracket near the wall:
[image: Bracket near wall]

Close up of the wall
[image: Close up of wall]

What should I do in order to re-attach this bracket to the wall?

Answer (score 3):

I would expect that behind the drywall at the bottom is a 2x4 plate running horizontally that the vertical studs rest on.  The bracket should be low enough that you can use a 2 inch screw and anchor to that.

You may want to repair the drywall before you put the bracket back.  Its hard to tell from the photos if the damage is light enough that you can fill it with joint compound or if you will need to patch the drywall. See [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/11594/how-do-i-fix-a-hole-in-drywall) for drywall repair tips.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly add a wooden or metal strap going from left to right across the face. It will cover up the damage and give it strength it needs. Ideally you would want to repair the damage and add a wooden stud behind the drywall that the screw would be able to go into rather than the drywall. But that is likely to cost and add a bit of work to it.