# Difficulty/Cost to repair drywall from tv mount?

Tags: drywall, hole, patching-drywall

So I have wall mounted a very large TV and my wall currently has a 1 foot x 1 foot hole that I used to install an outlet for power, there are like 8 holes in the wall, and then a 6" x 6" hole toward the bottom of the wall where my cables exit the wall.

I'm looking to sell my home within a couple of years and I would like the wall to look as new as possible.  What method is done to do this and will my wall look like it has undergone a repair or is it possible to have a nearly invisible repair done?

I still have the original pieces of drywall, but I have no experience in repairing anything like this.

Comment: potential duplicate of [How do I fix a hold in drywall?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/11594/how-do-i-fix-a-hole-in-drywall?lq=1), [What is the best method to patch a large hole (2-3 inches) in drywall?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/128/what-is-the-best-method-to-patch-a-large-hole-2-3-inches-in-drywall)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the willingness, then you can do it yourself. And, you'll get experience to use in the future.

Well I started describing what you need to do, but it was getting too long. And, I realized that you can find lots of video on this if you Google "drywall repair". So I think your best bet is to do that. Seeing it done is a lot more informative that reading about doing it.

Comment: this is not really an answer. you could describe the process and incorporate links to videos that you have found informative, that would then be an answer.

Comment: good points mac. didn't think of that. live and learn.

Comment: users are encouraged to edit their answers to improve them.